# How to construct a unique_ptr of a structure that contains an union?

Tags: c++, c++11, structure, unique-ptr, unions

I am trying to construct a `std::unique_ptr` pointer that contains an enum and and union of two elements that are structures as well:

```
struct button_t
{
  std::uint8_t id;
  std::uint16_t status;
};

struct led_t
{
  std::uint8_t id;
  std::uint16_t status;
};

struct message_t
{
  enum class id_e : std::uint8_t { button_e, led_e } id;
  union
  {
    button_t button;
    led_t led;
  };

  message_t(message_t::id_e id, const button_t& button) : id(id), button(button) {}
  message_t(message_t::id_e id, const led_t& led) : id(id), led(led) {}
};
```

When I tried to constuct a `std::unique_ptr` using `std::make_unique` as follows:

```
button_t button{56, 78};
typedef std::unique_ptr<message_t> p_msg_t;
auto msg = std::make_unique<p_msg_t>(message_t::id_e::button_event, button);
```

I got the following compilation error:

`error: no matching function for call to 'std::unique_ptr<message_t>::unique_ptr(message_t::id_e, button_t&)'`

Could anybody please help me identify where the problem lies?

Comment: make_unique doesn't take a pointer type. You should pass the type of the struct to make_unique, i.e. ```std::make_unique<message_t>```

Comment: Yes of course, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered in the comments. But note that you can avoid the redundant 'type' argument as you can infer it from the io object passed in to the constructor:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

struct button_t
{
  std::uint8_t id;
  std::uint8_t status;
};

struct led_t
{
  std::uint8_t id;
  std::uint16_t status;
};

struct message_t
{
  enum class id_e : std::uint8_t { button_e, led_e } id;
  union
  {
    button_t button;
    led_t led;
  };

  explicit message_t(const button_t& button) 
  : id(message_t::id_e::button_e)
  , button(button)
  {
  }

  explicit message_t(const led_t& led) 
  : id(message_t::id_e::led_e)
  , led(led)
  {
  }

};


int main()
{
    button_t button{56, 78};
    auto msg = std::make_unique<message_t>(button);
    msg = std::make_unique<message_t>(led_t { 43, 12 });
}
```

Comment: Should those ctors be explicit?  Always a good question to ask with 1 arg ctors.  (Answer is probably no here)

Comment: @Yakk tomato, tomAto isn't it? In this case we're talking about concrete things like buttons that we probably don't want inferred. It'd be a shame to mistake the ejector switch for the "seatbelt locked" light, so probably yes.